# PayMill iOS SDK: Swift 1.1 > 1.2 compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, closures, paymill

I am using [PayMill's iOS SDK](https://github.com/paymill/paymill-ios) in a Swift project.

I have an issue with their `PMManager.initWithTestMode()`, see [docs here](https://github.com/paymill/paymill-ios/blob/master/macos/PayMillSDK.framework/Versions/A/Headers/PMManager.h):

This code worked perfectly with Swift 1.1 and iOS 8.1 / 8.2:

```
PMManager.initWithTestMode(testMode, merchantPublicKey: publicKey, newDeviceId: nil,
    { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success{
            println("successfully initialized PayMillSDK")
        }
        else{
            println("error during initialization")
        }
    }
)
```

It gives me the following error:

> Missing argument label `init` in call

Adding `init:` before the closure will trigger more warnings.

How can I modify the above snippet to allow compatibility with iOS 8.3 / Swift 1.2?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `init` is now a reserved keyword. So there is no option in picking this as parameter name in Swift. In Objective-C however, this was possible.

Now thankfully it is possible to use this syntactic sugar:

```
PMManager.initWithTestMode(testMode, merchantPublicKey: publicKey, newDeviceId: nil)
    { (success, error) -> Void in
        if success{
            println("successfully initialized PayMillSDK")
        }
        else{
            println("error during initialization")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly. Everything compiles perfectly, and no errors in runtime as well. Thanks again! :-)